# How would I write a function that takes a sequence , and returns the same sequence with a mapping applied to only one element?

Tags: f#

Suppose I have the sequence `{1;2;3;4}` and I want to apply `(fun x -> x * 2)` to the 3rd element, yielding `{1;2;6;4}`. What's the best way to construct such a function ?

Comment: Seq.mapi with the position of the element as the extra input ; just change your double fun accordingly.

Comment: That would apply a mapping to every element of the sequence, which seems inefficient. Is there not a better way to do this ?

Comment: Sequences don't have indexing, so you are stuck iterating to at least the element you want to change

Comment: Why do you think it's inefficient?

Comment: Does is have to be a `seq` type, or if you are writing performance sensitive code, an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way of doing this while still treating the `seq` as a stream appropriately would be:

```
let input = seq {1..4} 
let result = input |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> match i with
                                           | 2 (* 3rd item *) -> x*2
                                           | _ -> x)
```